# Limitar numero de decimales sin redondear vb

Tags: vba, vb, vb6

Estoy mostrando el porcentaje de aciertos en una label. Calculé el porcentaje dividiendo dos contadores. El problema es que salen muchos decimales. Quiero que solo se muestren 3 pero no sé como hacerlo, espero puedan ayudarme

```
Sub Re()
Total= (CEH+CER)
Label10.text= ("Puntos obtenidos:" & (aciertos/ Total)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Para redondear numéricamente un resultado puedes usar en VBA ROUND

> [Función
> Round](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/round-function)

Aplicado a tu código, se quedaría algo así:

`Round(aciertos/ Total, 2)`